# Merge two lines in a time series in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series

I have a time series that sometimes has two entries for the same date. I want to merge the two dates using the sum of the values. Eg:

```
date  id  x   y
d1    1  100  0   
d1    1  0   20
d2    1  80   0
d2    1  0   30
d3    1  110  0
d3    1  0   15
d3    2  70  60
```

In this case, d1 repeats for id 1, so they be merged. The end result would be for this case date = d1, id = 1, x = 100, y = 20

Comment: can you post the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you want to groupby and sum:

```
df.groupby(["date", "id"]).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  date  id    x   y
0   d1   1  100  20
1   d2   1   80  30
2   d3   1  110  15
3   d3   2   70  60
```